# JNA Java - Callback only work when there is no Jframe

Tags: java, swing, callback, jframe, jna

I've programmed a DLL in C. The first function sends a pointer of the callback function that is called when new data is available.

So I use JNA to wrap this function.

In order to avoid the end of the app, I use an InputStreamReader that wait data from the standard input. And when new data are available the callback is called and data are printed in the console.

But, if I use a JFrame to avoid the end of the program before closing the window, it doesn’t work properly. In fact, if I don’t resize the JFrame window, the callback is called about 30 times and after that nothing (even if new data are available). If I resize the window, the callback if never called (even if new data are available).

Please could you help me?

Thanks

Edit : This is my main method.

```
    package jsigmausblib;
```

`import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JSigmaUSBLib {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeSigmaUSBLibInterface  nsuli = (NativeSigmaUSBLibInterface) Native.loadLibrary("SigmaUSBLib1.0", NativeSigmaUSBLibInterface.class);

        ReadCallback rc = new ReadCallback() {
            @Override
                public void callbackFunction(Pointer readData, byte len) {
                    System.out.println("ok"+readData.getByte(0));
                }
        };

        SigmaUSBLibConfigStruct.ByValue config = new SigmaUSBLibConfigStruct.ByValue();

        nsuli.SigmaUSBLibInit(rc , config);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Debug");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(80, 60);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}`

Comment: It's hard for me to see what's going wrong based on your description above. I want to suspect that it is a Swing threading error, that your application is somehow tying up the EDT or Swing event thread, but again, I can't tell based on what you're telling me so far. Consider telling and showing more.

Comment: Again, how are you implementing all of this? Again, is your code respecting Swing threading rules?

Comment: What kinds of details do you need?

Comment: It's hard to say. We need to know enough information that would allow us to help you solve the problem, like how you're integrating your stream reader with your Swing code. Imagine you're us and that someone whose code you are completely unfamiliar with is asking you this same question. Sitting in our shoes, what would you ask him to show you?

Comment: I've added my main method with the problem of the JFrame.

Comment: I've point out that if I add a Thread.sleep(1000); before the JFrame and if the new data come before the JFrame initialization, it works. Very strange !!

Comment: @user979128 Like HFOE said, hard to tell. But I would try to 1. Move the initialization of the UI (creation of JFrame etc...) to the EDT by wrapping the initialization of the UI code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater. 2. Move your call the JNA in a SwingWorker. The SwingWorker should be started from the EDT, after initializing the UI.

Comment: I agree 100% with @Guillaume's post. Also, is the JFrame an integral part of your program, or are you using it just to create a Swing thread so that the JVM will persist? If the latter, then I advise you not to do this that there are better thread techniques to keep the JVM alive.

Comment: Currently the Jframe if just required to create a Swing thread so that the JVM will persist. But I'll need it to do my GUI later. I tried to to invoke later the GUI initialization and put my JNA code in a SwingWorker, but it's the same thing.

Comment: I become crazy. With all the code in the main method without runnable..., if I start the app with Netbeans debugger, it works well.

Comment: If you want to avoid the JVM exiting, spawn a non-daemon thread which exits on some other signal.

If you want to ensure that a native thread doesn't get starved, make sure all your threads occasionally give up execution, typically by calling Thread.yield() or Thread.sleep().

The problem likely comes with distribution of processing time among threads in your process.  Creating a JFrame simply adds another thread into the mix (one which has its own idiosyncracies).  Running under the Netbeans debugger yet more threading side effects.